# Access the path to jacocoagent.jar in gradle using the JaCoCo plugin?

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, jacoco

Is there a way to access the path to the jacocoagent.jar used by the Gradle JaCoCo plugin?

I want to use to use it in JVM arguments to get code coverage when testing a GAE dev instance.

e.g.

```
jvmFlags = ["-javaagent:${<path to agent jar>}=destfile=${buildDir}/jacoco/jacoco.exec"]
```

Also, is there a better way of getting jacoco coverage of a GAE?

Comment: If your project has valid Unit tests, then during the build, the jacocoagent.jar will be created at $WORKSPACE/build/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco.*/jacocoagent.jar. Instead of depending on whether a project has Unit tests or not, you can either check-in the jacocoagent.jar in the project source code OR place a copy of the file in your project/jobs WORKSPACE/../jacocoagent folder location and use it (relative to the project's workspace). If the project doesn't have Unit tests (src/test/java /defined in sourceSets) then you won't find the .jar in build/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco* folder.